# Differences between signalr1 and signalr2

Tags: signalr

I do not find what is different between versions 1 and 2 of signalr.

Is there a really value add to work with signal r 2?
On nugget gallery, i only see signalr. There are no distinction to work even with version 1 or 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Main differences:**
SignalR 2 implements OWIN

Also lot of bugfixes and security issues eliminates.

For SignalR 2x you need .NET 4.5 and for 1x .NET 4.0

See release history
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/releases

(Nuget loads always the newest version in the case you do not define something other)